# MySQL performance issues with big tables and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, large-data

I have three tables, wp_posts(60000 records), wp_postmeta(130000 records) and news_news_obj(70000 records).
I want to find all the posts from news_news_obj table that are missing from the table wp_posts. 
The comparison is made with news_news_obj.id with a custom field that every posts has in wp_postmeta table (oldpostid).

I tried with the 2 queries below first with a limit 30 and the one with NOT IN is faster from the one with the Joins.
The problem is that when I remove the LIMIT the query takes reaaaly too long.. I tried leaving it for a couple of hours and it didn't returned any results.

What can I do for this kind of problem and so big data?

Any help appreciated!

The first query with the joins:

```
SELECT  meta2.id, meta2.title, meta2.main_text
    FROM  wp_posts
    INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta meta1  ON meta1.post_id = wp_posts.ID
      AND  meta1.meta_key = 'oldpostid'
      AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    RIGHT JOIN  news_news_obj meta2  ON meta1.meta_value = meta2.id
    WHERE  meta1.meta_value IS NULL
```

The second query I tried with NOT IN:

```
SELECT  news_news_obj.id, news_news_obj.title, news_news_obj.main_text
    FROM  news_news_obj
    WHERE  news_news_obj.id NOT IN (
        SELECT  wp_postmeta.meta_value
            FROM  wp_posts, wp_postmeta
            WHERE  wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
              AND  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'oldpostid'
              AND  wp_postmeta.meta_value = news_news_obj.id
              AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
              AND  wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
                          )
```

Comment: Is there are reason the second query cares about 'publish' and the first one doesn't? Also, given the size of the tables I am not positive; but taking out `AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = news_news_obj.id` from the subquery in the second version may help (since it will no longer be a correlated subquery, mysql can process the subquery once instead once for each outer row.)

Comment: No there is no reason, I just forgot to add it to the first query. For now my main concern is to just get the results with either one of the queries in a resonable time limit.

Comment: Because this is the part that I'm checking if the post exists in the second table do you have any idea how can be done in a different way if I remove this part?

Comment: The second query uses a correlated subquery, and I think that correlation is not necessary; Try second query without condition `wp_postmeta.meta_value = news_news_obj.id`.

Comment: You were right, it wasn't necessary, now I get it. But still the performance is terrible... I tried it with a LIMIT 100 and I took 160sec. So still I can't get all the results at all.

Comment: Hm - can you try out how long it takes to execute only the subquery? How many rows does this subquery return? Try (though I don't think that it helps) to write `select distinct meta_value ...` in the subquery...

Comment: The DISTINCT didn't make any difference. The subquery it takes only 0.0276sec and it returns 70.000 rows.

Comment: Just to make sure, is `news_news_obj.id` indexed?

Comment: Yes the news_news_obj.id is indexed.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the `NOT IN` and the `JOIN` -- I want to see why you got the difference.  Also, which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Do you want `FROM x INNER JOIN (y RIGHT JOIN z)` or `FROM (x INNER JOIN y) RIGHT JOIN z)`?  Please add parens to clarify; then check that you still get the 'right' results.

Answer (score 0):

(See my Comments, plus...)

Indexes needed:

```
posts:  INDEX(post_status, post_type, ID)
posts:  INDEX(post_type, ID)
postmeta:  PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key)
```

The two queries will potentially get different results because only one has

```
AND  wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```